# How to get the definition of the existing datastore CTXSYS (created for indexing) in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How to get the definition of the existing datastore CTXSYS (used for indexing) in oracle?

For example one of a column in table t1 has a context index type  with datastore CTXSYS.t1_example_test,

is there any table or any way that can help me to find the definition of "CTXSYS.t1_example_test"?

I just want to know which all columns are included in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for,

Any text index created can be found in `CTXSYS` schema as shown below and the indexed column name is in column `IDX_TEXT_NAME`

```
select c.idx_name,c.idx_table,c.idx_text_name
  from ctxsys.ctx_indexes c
 where c.idx_table = <table_name>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I searched for the value in all tables of schema ctxsys and finally found the value that I want using the below query.

**select prv_value from ctxsys.DR$PREFERENCE_VALUE where PRV_OAT_ID=10701;**